# SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I am running this it gives me an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here

```
var React = require("react");

module.exports = React.createClass({
    constructor(){
       super();
       this.state = {date: new Date()};
    },
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                test
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

PS. I removed `super()` it gave me an error

> You are attempting to define `constructor` on your component more than once. This conflict may be due to a mixin.

Example is from [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class)

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're using `React.createClass`. If you want to use `constructor()`, you'll have to switch your syntax to ES6 class definition, like the docs. In your case: `module.exports = class MyComponent extends React.Component {`.

Comment: `super` is for ES6 `class`es only, not for `React.createClass`.

Comment: @mrlew Thanks, it solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using ES6 classes, but the `React.createClass()` syntax, set the initial state via `getInitialState()`, not via a constructor:

```
var Counter = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {count: this.props.initialCount};
  },
  // ...
});
```

[More info in the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html#setting-the-initial-state)

---

That said, it would be best practice to switch to ES6 classes instead. This way you can use the constructor syntax from the docs.